# API does not return stackoverflow user_id?

Tags: bug

When I visit 
http://stackauth.com/1.1/users/aa1073f7-7e3b-4d4d-ace5-f2fca853f998/associated 
it returns my user_id on many stackexchange sites, but not 
stackoverflow itself!

I'm sure this is by design or someone's noticed it already, but could 
I get some guidance here? This behavior breaks 
https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/blob/master/bc-stack2wp.pl

Comment: Are your account associations set up properly? What association GUID do you get for your Stack Overflow account?

Comment: http://stackexchange.com/users/aa1073f7-7e3b-4d4d-ace5-f2fca853f998?tab=accounts shows my stackoverflow account (and many others)